# Testing AsyncStorage with Redux Thunk

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage

When I try to test if a Cat is added correctly to the Async Storage I am receiving null. How can I solve this? In the app is working correctly. I am using React Native, React-Native-Async-Storage, Redux Thunk and Redux Persist.

REDUCER

```
export const INITIAL_STATE: CatsState = {
  cats: [],
  selectedCat: null
}

const catsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: CatsAction): CatsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CatsActionTypes.SET_CATS:
      return { ...state, cats: action.payload }
    case CatsActionTypes.SELECT_CAT:
      return { ...state, selectedCat: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

ACTION

```
export const addCat = ({ cat }: AddCatData): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, CatsAction> => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<CatsAction>) => {
    try {
      const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.cats)
      const cats: Cat[] = response ? JSON.parse(response) : []

      cats.push(cat)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEYS.cats, JSON.stringify(cats))
      dispatch({ type: CatsActionTypes.SET_CATS, payload: cats })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

TEST

```
beforeEach(async () => await AsyncStorage.clear())
describe('add cat', () => {
  it('persist cat correctly into local storage', async () => {
    const cat: Cat = {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Cat',
      breed: 'Breed',
      age: 1,
      gender: 'male',
      weight: 5,
      size: 'Big',
      color: 'Brown',
      mood: 'Angry',
      description: 'Cat description',
      friendly: 3,
      liked: true
    }

    addCat({ cat })
    const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.cats)
    const cats: Cat[] = JSON.parse(response)
    const expectedArray = { cats: [cat] }
    expect(cats).toStrictEqual(expectedArray)
  })
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use official documentation `react-native-async-storage` package: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest

**UPDATED:**

For you case you need do several steps:

#1 Mock your data

```
const CAT_MOCK = {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Cat',
}
```

#2 Mock Storage

```
const STORAGE_MOCK = {
    [STORAGE_KEYS.cats]: [CAT_MOCK]
}
```

#3 Mock library for your case

```
jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage', () => ({
    getItem: jest.fn((item) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(STORAGE_MOCK[item]);
        });
    }),
}));
```

Comment: I have already done that and still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, after mock library you need add mock for you cases. I get you example

Comment: Thank you, but what I don't understand is the part of mockItems[item] =(

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated answer. Use `STORAGE_MOCK[item]` instead `mockItems[item]`